# When to recompile resource.qrc with pyrcc5

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyrcc5

In QGIS3 plugin tutorials that use the plugin builder, it says to run `pyrcc5` before importing the plugin.
After what changes should `pyrcc5` be run again? I have managed to modify some plugins by changing some of the Python code and the changes were there when the plugin was reloaded, without me recompiling.

I read [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/resources.html) that `pyrcc5` compiles the `resource.qrc` file, but I don't really know what that file is for. The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) mentions icons, so am I right in presuming that I would have to recompile only after changing the additional images (icons, etc.) provided to the plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [The Qt Resource System
Documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/resources.html) says,
the main reason of using resource file is to avoid the risk of losing the files.

`pyrcc5` generates **all in one binary-like string** which contains all resource files defined in `.qrc` file, and adds that string to `.py` file (in this case, `resources.py`), then you import that module (`from .resources import *` or `from pluginname.resources import *`)

When you add -for example- a new 'icon' to `.qrc` file or modify the icon file content, you have to run `pyrcc5` again to modify `resources.py`.

---

I work on different OS and computers. I prefer not to to use `.qrc` file or run `pyrcc5` again, to avoid getting errors with `pyrcc5`. Instead, I use the full path of the file using the following structure. That's personal choice.

- Usage without resource file:

  ```py
    plg_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    # icons: folder containing my icon files
    icon_path = os.path.join(plg_dir, "icons", "zoom.png")
    # OR icon_path = plg_dir  + '/icons/zoom.png'

    icon = QIcon(icon_path)
  ```
- Usage with resource file:

  Before, you should generate a `resource.py` file using `pyrcc5`.

  ```py
    from .resources import *
    .
    .

    icon_path = ':/icons/zoom.png'
    icon = QIcon(icon_path)
  ```

  Content of resources.qrc:

  ```py
    <!DOCTYPE RCC>
    <RCC version="1.0">
        <qresource>
            <file>icons/zoom.png</file>
            ...
        </qresource>
    </RCC>
  ```