# Changing the Processing plugin icon - QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have built a processing plugin which shows up in the QGIS Processing Toolbox. However, I am struggling trying to change the icon. Usually I do:

`pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc`

and it updates perfectly.

However, I do not have a

`resources.py`

file so I cannot adopt this approach. Is there another way to update it?

Comment: You may want to look at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/350074/29431) for another approach that uses an icon file directly instead of using `qrc` file. So that you don't need to use `pyrcc5` and to generate `resource.py` file.

Comment: I tried that but it doesnt seem to work either. Thanks

Comment: It should work. How did you try?

Comment: You said "*it updates perfectly*". What I understand is "*it creates `resources.py` successfully*". If not so, what do you mean by "*it updates perfectly*"?

Comment: I'm confused - where did I say that? I don't have a "resources.py" for this plugin

Comment: In your question body, there is a line -> "*and  it updates perfectly*". I mean this line. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Oh I see - I don't have a resources.py this time as when using the plugin builder for creating a processing plugin, it doesnt create a resources.qrc file.

Answer (score 4):

I was also looking for a way to do this too and found out the way. The command

```
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

will **generate** `resources.py` using the `resources.qrc` is input.

To change your icon:

1. create the file `resources.qrc` with content like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/plugins/your_plugin" >
        <file>logo.svg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

2. Make sure `logo.svg` or your icon is in the root directory of your plugin.
3. Run: `pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc`

To reiterate, `resources.py` does not exist before you run this command. `resources.py` **will be generated** after this command.

4. Import `resources.py` in your script and call for the icon:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingProvider
from . import resources

class YourAlgorithmProvider(QgsProcessingProvider):
    # some class definitions here
    def icon(self):
        return QIcon(':/plugins/your_plugin/logo.svg')
```